# How to optimize a query when grouping on a date / unix timestamp?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

I'm not very used to MySQL, but I think it can be much faster than it is.

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `crashes` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `added_date` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `issue_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `report_id` text NOT NULL,
 `app_version_code` text NOT NULL,
 `app_version_name` text NOT NULL,
 `package_name` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
 `package_name_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
 `file_path` text NOT NULL,
 `phone_model` text NOT NULL,
 `android_version` text NOT NULL,
 `build` text NOT NULL,
 `brand` text NOT NULL,
 `product` text NOT NULL,
 `total_mem_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `available_mem_size` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `custom_data` text NOT NULL,
 `stack_trace` text NOT NULL,
 `initial_configuration` text NOT NULL,
 `crash_configuration` text NOT NULL,
 `display` text NOT NULL,
 `user_comment` text NOT NULL,
 `user_app_start_date` text NOT NULL,
 `user_crash_date` text NOT NULL,
 `dumpsys_meminfo` text NOT NULL,
 `dropbox` text NOT NULL,
 `logcat` text NOT NULL,
 `eventslog` text NOT NULL,
 `radiolog` text NOT NULL,
 `is_silent` text NOT NULL,
 `device_id` text NOT NULL,
 `installation_id` text NOT NULL,
 `user_email` text NOT NULL,
 `device_features` text NOT NULL,
 `environment` text NOT NULL,
 `settings_system` text NOT NULL,
 `settings_secure` text NOT NULL,
 `shared_preferences` text NOT NULL,
 `application_log` text NOT NULL,
 `media_codec_list` text NOT NULL,
 `thread_details` text NOT NULL,
 `user_ip` text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `package_name_id` (`package_name_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=202364 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

As you can see it's filled with 200k rows. I'd like to retrieve the row `added_date` (unix timestamp, `int(11)`), and number of rows on that day.

So I select the date, day (as Y-M-D), and count:

```
SELECT date_format(from_unixtime(added_date), '%Y-%c-%d') as date, added_date, count(*) as nb_crashes FROM crashes WHERE package_name = 'net.bicou.redmine' GROUP BY date ORDER BY date ASC
```

It's very slow! Almost 1.5sec on a dedicated mysql server on my host.

So I figured I could optimize the thing a little bit: I added a package_name_id that is a `tinyint`, which is unique per `package_name` (I have 5 different `package_name` values on that 200k rows). I made that an `INDEX` so that MySQL can browse it faster.
Result: 0.9sec. That's much better, but still off the performance I'm expecting!

How could I optimize the thing? I guess creating the date on each row, then grouping is very expensive. However I don't know how I could make this faster...

Edit:

Here's what I did to update the table:

```
ALTER TABLE  `crashes` ADD  `temp` DATETIME NOT NULL
UPDATE crashes SET temp = FROM_UNIXTIME( added_date )
ALTER TABLE  `crashes` ADD INDEX (  `temp` )
```

Here's the updated query:

```
SELECT added_date, count(*) as nb_crashes FROM crashes WHERE package_name_id=3 GROUP BY year(temp),month (temp),dayofmonth(temp) ORDER BY temp ASC
```

I've still got execution times of around one second... Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using unix timestamp values if you ever need to query against that field in a date-like way. You should use date, datetime, or timestamp field types.

Why?

Because if you want to do something like query results for a specific date or group records by date, you will always have to use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` in order to do so.  This function call will prevent you from using any sort of index on the date value if you are trying to use it for sorts, joins, where filters, groups, etc.  There is nothing you can do to improve your query outside of using the proper data type and then indexing the fields you are going to be using for sorts, filters, joins, groups, etc.

Really the use of unix timestamps in DB's seems to be proliferated by inexperienced PHP developers who think that it is easier to work with dates in this format in PHP (either they are too lazy to convert date/datetime DB output to unix timestamps in PHP, or they have not figured out how to use dateTime and dateInterval PHP classes to make working with dates in PHP easier).

My suggestion is to break this habit now and start learning how to work with date/datetime fields in MySQL.

Antoher thing I would suggest looking at your table DDL is that you probably should revisit the use of text fields there.  Most of those cases look like they might better be varchar fields.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm a dirty php dev that learned as an amateur 10 years ago, I just started again. I'll do things right then, thanks a lot for the hints.

Comment: Hey, I've updated my question because I'm still unable to optimize my table the way I want it. About those `text` fields, they're not used in selection, join or group so I assumed it didn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you need performance, you need an index, and if you need an index, then you need to create a column with the right kind of data in it before you do your query.

This requires creating an additional column and populating it with the result of your transformation, plus inserting all new rows with that column populated correctly.

Why are you storing your date as a timestamp instead of as a proper `DATE` column, anyway?

Comment: Thanks. See my comment on Mike's answer. I'll convert the field to a date field!

Comment: Good plan, and Mike does have a more thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an index on both the `package_name` and the `added_date` columns. Also, change your `ORDER BY` to order by `added_date` instead of by `date`, since ordering by `date` would probably need a filesort step.

In any case `EXPLAIN` helps diagnose the query better.

Comment: This still won't help all that much in that he still needs to group by calculated date field, which is not able to use an index at all.  Only solution here is to use proper date/datetime data type in the field.